# Which preposition should be used?

Tags: prepositions

> We are naturally concerned very much by/about our appearance.

In this sentence, which preposition should be used, *by* or *about*? Are there any other prepositions used after the word "concerned"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would pick "about", since "by" seems to imply wilful action.

Comment: Thank you, CopperKettle. I found the sentence in a test question.

Comment: @CopperK - I would choose "about" also, but for a different reason. We simply tend to use [_about_ more than _by_ with _concerned_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=concerned+by%2Cconcerned+about&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: BTW I think you should say: _very much concerned_ **not** _concerned very much_

Answer (score 3):

"About" is the correct choice because "by" implies action on the part of "appearance". E.G.

> I was pulled over **by** a trooper
>
> He was hit **by** a bus
>
> That book is **by** John Smith

Alternately, you might use "concerned with", but really "concerned about" is most common.

Answer (score 1):

I could depend on "how" (by what method) you saw yourselves -- perhaps in a mirror, on a TV broadcast, reflected in a window, or in your minds' eyes?

In other words, if it was a physical sight, a reflection for example, then "by" is appropriate. This is like saying, "when I saw my reflection, I was shocked by it."

If you are thinking about how you look, then "about" is more appropriate, as the previous answer says. "I spent a lot of time getting dressed because I was concerned about my appearance."